# Force child windows to stay on parent's workspace

Tags: unity, window-manager

I am a heavy user of multiple workspaces, and often find an application, say, on workspace 2 will open a child window on the currently active workspace 3 where I have my web browser. Is there a way to configure Unity to keep child windows on the same workspace as their parent?